# Finding expressions using graphs

Tags: triangles

Here is a question

Anyone know how to solve this or any hints to get me started as I am stuck.

> The diagram shows a triangle ABC with sides BC a and AC b
>   The points D,E and F lie on the sides AC,AB and BC, respectively,
>   so that CDEF is a rhombus with sides of length x.
>
> Find a expression for x in terms of a and b
>   [image]

Comment: Similar triangles?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whatever $\angle BCA$ is, by similarity of $\triangle BFE$ and $\triangle BCA$ we must have
$$\frac{a-x}x=\frac ab$$
$$b(a-x)=ba-bx=ax$$
$$ab=(a+b)x$$
$$x=\frac{ab}{a+b}$$

Comment: I got $$x=\frac{ab}{a+b}$$,ok, just edited.